# haproxy how to make it switch to a different backend in case of 404

Tags: http, websocket, http-status-code-404, load-balancing, haproxy

I need your help.
I have implemented a haproxy configuration which correctly manages both *http* and *websocket* backends, except in one specific scenario.

Here below a summary about how this stuff works:

When I connect to **:2703/webapp**, haproxy correctly redirects to one of the two http configured backends (webapp-lb1 or webapp-lb2).

When I connect to **:2703/webapp/events**, haproxy correctly redirects to one of the two websocket configured backends (websocket-lb1 or websocket-lb2)

*Webapp* is a servlet running in apache tomcat. 
When I stop one of the two backend tomcats, haproxy correctly switches to the other one (for both the http and the websocket).

On the contrary, when I try to simulate an outage of one of the http backends by stopping the webapp via the tomcat manager, haproxy reports a **HTTP Status 404** error but **does not switch** to the other backend.

Being that I explicitly configured the *http-check expect status 302* directive, I would expect that - in case of a 404 status - haproxy switches to the other backend.

I had a look at the haproxy official documentation and I also tested the *http-check disable-on-404* configuration but this is not what I need, as the haproxy behavior remains exactly the same of the above one.

For info, activating the *http-check disable-on-404*, haproxy detects the DOWN of the backend I stopped but does nothing (which as far as I understand, is exactly what we have to expect from the *http-check disable-on-404* configuration in case of 404 status); here below the haproxy log when this option is enabled:

```
Jul 23 14:19:23 localhost haproxy[4037]: Server webapp-lb/webapp-lb2 is stopping, reason: Layer7 check conditionally passed, code: 404, info: "Not Found", check duration: 0ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
```

Here below an extract of my haproxy configuration:

```
frontend haproxy-webapp
bind *:2703
monitor-uri /haproxy_check
stats enable
stats uri /haproxy_stats
stats realm Strictly Private
stats auth admin:zqxwcevr
acl is_websocket url_beg /webapp/events
use_backend websocket-lb if is_websocket
default_backend webapp-lb
log global

backend webapp-lb
server webapp-lb1 192.168.136.129:8888 maxconn 400 check cookie webapp-lb1
server webapp-lb2 192.168.136.130:8888 maxconn 400 check cookie webapp-lb2
balance roundrobin
cookie JSESSIONID prefix nocache
log global
#http-check disable-on-404
option httpchk GET /webapp
http-check expect status 302

backend websocket-lb
server websocket-lb1 192.168.136.129:8888 maxconn 400 check
server websocket-lb2 192.168.136.130:8888 maxconn 400 check
balance roundrobin
log global
```

Please give me a hint as I am spending ages in reading documentation and forums with no success.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you confusing health check behavior and normal runtime behavior?  The 404 on a check will cause a health check to fail and take the instance out of service, but a 404 on a live request returns the 404 to the client.  Once a response is received from a server, it is returned to the client.  Nothing is retried once the request is submitted to a server.

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks. Yes, I am a little confused there. I was expecting the health check (running a GET on /webapp) to detect the 404 and react accordingly, taking the instace out of service and switching to the good one. Which configuration do you suggest to change/add in order to make haproxy able to do that? I hope this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: *"haproxy detects the DOWN of the backend I stopped but does nothing"* Define "does nothing."

Comment: When it detects the DOWN, it does not switch to the other running backend instance. This is only when I stop my servlet via the tomcat manager. When I stop the tomcat, haproxy switches correctly. Thx.